# Giving a programmatically-created Dialog's buttons the default style of dialog buttons

Tags: android, dialog, android-styles

I'm creating a Dialog (not AlertDialog, and don't tell me to use one because it would give another unsolvable problem) programmatically, with its own layout hierarchy (code below). Since I'm using a Dialog and not an AlertDialog, there's no "setPositive/NegativeButton" method so I must create the buttons as I do with the other views of the Dialog. The problem is that while the other Views use the default dialog style, the buttons don't. I tried all that I could, looked on the internet and in the source codes for the default themes and styles for dialogs, debugged the program to find the theme used by the dialog and apply it to the buttons, but nothing worked. The style of the buttons is never the right one.

here's the code:

```
    dialog = new Dialog(context);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    ListView listView = new ListView(context);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    relativeLayout.addView(listView);

    LinearLayout buttonsLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    buttonsLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonsLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    buttonsLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    buttonsLayout.setLayoutParams(buttonsLayoutParams);

    Button cancelButton = null;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
        cancelButton = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
    //this seems to use the right style for buttons on android <= 2.3.3

    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        cancelButton = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));
    //this is not the right style. see image below

    } else {
        cancelButton = new Button(context);
        cancelButton.setBackgroundColor(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
    //this sets the background color of the buttons to match the one of the dialog,
    //but this way the buttons have no visible margins and click animation
    }

    cancelButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    cancelButton.setText("Cancel");
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button sendButton = null;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
        sendButton = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
    //this seems to use the right style for buttons on android <= 2.3.3

    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        sendButton = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));
    //this is not the right style. see image below

    } else {
        sendButton = new Button(context);
        sendButton.setBackgroundColor(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
    //this sets the background color of the buttons to match the one of the dialog,
    //but this way the buttons have no visible margins and click animation
    }

    sendButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    sendButton.setText("Send");
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //do something

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    buttonsLayout.addView(cancelButton);
    buttonsLayout.addView(sendButton);

    relativeLayout.addView(buttonsLayout);

    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setContentView(relativeLayout);
    dialog.setTitle("Insert");
    dialog.show();
```

here's the result in android > 2.3.3 && <= 3.2:

[image: android > 2.3.3 && <= 3.2]

and the result on android > 3.2:

[image: android > 3.2]

(sorry for the buttons edited with paint, ahah)

Comment: Why would `AlertDialog` produce an unsolvable problem?

Comment: If you use an alertdialog that has a list whose items have edittexts and that list uses an adapter, the keyboard won't show up when you select an edittext. I tried every solution I found but the only one that made the keyboard show up made it appear behind the alertdialog, rendering it useless.